# Changing views works in viewDidLoad but not on a button click IBAction

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to open up a new view with the identifier `AddSourceViewController` when a button is clicked. I'm using the following code to do so:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddSourceViewController"];
[vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

When used in `viewDidLoad` on an initial view, this code works perfectly and opens up the additional view. However, I have added an IBAction to a button on the initial view and when I add the above code to attempt to open the new view on button click, I just get a `Thread 1: breakpoint 5.1 6.1`. How can I get this to work on the button action?

EDIT: Better error information below.

```
2012-11-23 16:33:40.399 Marketr[23454:c07] -[SecondViewController addSourceButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e2f5c0
2012-11-23 16:33:40.400 Marketr[23454:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SecondViewController addSourceButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e2f5c0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a breakpoint set for your action method?  Look on the left side next to the code of this method, to see if there is a blue arrow pointing towards the code.

Comment: Well, in my .h I see `@implementation` a synthesized thing and a blank line with blue arrows. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: If you see a blue arrow, that's a break point. Look at the top, center of Xcode. You'll see an arrow icon, click that to turn off all breakpoints. Then try running again.

Comment: It always takes me to this `@autoreleasepool` when it fails with `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Comment: Ok, look at the bottom section. That will give you some details about why it crashed. Skip the hexadecimal stuff and paste the rest as an edit to your question

Comment: Ok your button is trying to call addSourceButton in your SecondViewController. Does that method exist in that class?  Look VERY closely for typos in the method name in the .m file.

Comment: I added two actions - addButton and addSourceButton and forgot to get rid of addSourceButton. I should delete this question, shouldn't I? I guess it doesn't exactly contribute because it ended up not really being related to what the initial problem conveys.

Comment: I can't delete. I'll just select your answer. Thanks for all the help! If you have a minute, could you direct me to where to look for linking this view in the storyboard with a view controller class I created? Googling isn't yielding any results so I'm assuming I'm not using the right terms.

Comment: On the right side, put your mouse over the top selectors. One is called "Identity Inspector". In that panel, when the VC is selected you can set the Custom Class